# Calling WCF 4.0 Rest Service with json

Tags: wcf, rest

I created a new wcf rest service using .net 4.
I have created a new service based on the example one and referenced it in the global.asax file so I can browse to it ok.

My problem is I get the results back in xml not json. This is my service code

```
  [ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
// NOTE: If the service is renamed, remember to update the global.asax.cs file
public class CheckIfValid
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{id}/details.json",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public SampleItem Get(string id)
    {
        // TODO: Return the instance of SampleItem with the given id
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if(id=="123")
        return new SampleItem { Id = 1, StringValue = "Got it" };
        else
            return new SampleItem { Id = 2, StringValue = "Not valid fool..." };
    }
}
```

Very basic but I am just trying to get my head around it. The returned result looks like this

```
<SampleItem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfRestService1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Id>1</Id><StringValue>Got it</StringValue></SampleItem>
```

I have tried browsing to the help section in the service but the json example doesnt do anything.

Can anyone suggest what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making the request via Fiddler instead of using a web browser?  Many browsers will not render any JSON they get back.

Comment: regarding displaying json in the browser, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-dow

Comment: @Cheeso  Nice to know that you can do that, but you still won't pry fiddler from my cold, dead hands. :-)  Debugging REST services via a browser is just a massive exercise in frustration.

Comment: Thanks Darrel. Doh feel abit stupid for not testing in fiddler

Comment: @Darrel - I use fiddler pretty much every day, so I agree with you. It's indispensable. There are so many cool features beyond just tracing the HTTP messages. You can intercept traffic, script modifications, set breakpoints. It's a great tool. Even so, sometimes it's nice to see json in the browser.

Comment: Is there any reason why this piece of jqeury is returning anything?   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:41625/checkcard/1/details.json', function (data) {
                $('.result').html('<p>' + data.StringValue + '</p>'
    + '<p>' + data.Id + '</p>');
            });

        });

   
    </script>

Comment: @user293545  Looks good to me, but then I'm definitely not a jQuery guy.