# I'm getting an XML error messages for JSON?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, vb.net, json

**UPDATE 2:**

I did not mention that I do not get the error below in Chromium, but I do get it in IE8.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 May 2011 15:40:23 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 85
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a serverside page which generates json data, which works perfectly well when accessed by jquery.  However, when i navigate to the webpage which actually generates the json data, I get the following clientside error message in the browser:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'http://companyname.com/json/data.aspx?id=7

[{"key":7,"value":"Default"}]
```

Why does that happen and how can I stop the error message from appearing?

Comment: Which response headers does the web page send?

Comment: That's the official content type, so I assume your browser can't display JSON.  I think that's OK, why would your users want to open JSON in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears, because the JSON data is probably served as type text/xml and your browser tries to interpret the output as XML. If you served it as application/json that would probably not happen. Why would you want to directly access the page though?

Comment: I'm sending the json data back as `Response.ContentType = "application/json"`.

Comment: Please check out update 1 above for proof of this from the response headers.

Comment: See this related question about IE8 and JSON data:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-dow

Comment: Seems like IE directs `application/json` to the XML viewer which itself tries to transform XML with an XML stylesheet - and fails miserably on the "invalid XML".

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here, `context.Response.ContentType="text/plain";`
 made my day...

Comment: This resolved my issue. Answer "http://stackoverflow.com/a/6070509/24975" did not.

Comment: The semantically correct type is still application/json and it is probably a IE limitation that produces the error if it works in Chrome. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do) referenced above on IE's JSON Support.

Comment: `text/plain` worked for me. Be sure to set `dataType: 'json'` in your call to `$.ajax()`. According to jQuery docs: "If none (dataType) is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response ". I take that to mean if you use `text/plain`, jQuery is just going pass a string to your success function.

Comment: This also fixed my issue. I was using jquery-file-upload so the contentType was being set for me (multipart) and I needed to return JSON from a handler. It worked in Chrome but not IE8, gave me `Invalid at the top level of the document` error. Switching to `text/plain` solved it even though it's not "correct."

Answer (score 0):

Two tips here:
1) Install HttpFox Addon in Firefox which allows you to see exactly what is being sent/received
2) Install JSON View in Firefox which allows you to view JSON response in the browser.

Comment: Please see update 1 in the original question.  I don't have firefox, but according to chromium the response header show in update 1 is what it is returning.