# View JSON file in Browser

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

It is not a programming question, but need your views in few words.

When we hit the JSON  url in Broswer, it asks us to save the file. 
Why this happens ? 
Is there any way to view it on the page itself ?
Is there any addon available to view JSON file in browser?

Comment: I presume it is IE you are using, if you use Chrome it will show on the page. but if you change the Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 it should allow you to view it in page

Comment: @Qpirate Content-Type of ideal JSON file is always json. It can't be text/html. Do you have any solution for Firefox/IE? Vodun solved it for chrome.

Comment: Same for firefox: http://jsonview.com/

Comment: @Umesh Sorry my thoughts on wanting to see the json returned was so you could debug the response, hence changing the response type. i dont try to view my JSON being returned in the browser mostly i just use fiddler to see what is being returned. sorry.

Comment: I installed the addon. But it doesn't work for my file - http://content.dimestore.com/prod/survey_data/4535/4535.json

Comment: Because the server return invalid "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" should be "application/json"

Comment: Where "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" is mentioned ?

Comment: In the http header. You can see it with curl -v content.dimestore.com/prod/survey_data/4535/4535.json

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convince IE to simply display application/json rather than offer to download it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Chrome use [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)
or Firefox use [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/)

Comment: @Umesh https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/ for firefox ... added to answer

Comment: How to use this add on ? I installed, but when I hit the json url. It saves in browser downloads

Comment: @Umesh read the help on the plugin page ----> Normally when encountering a JSON document (content type "application/json"), Firefox simply prompts you to download the file. With the JSONView extension, JSON documents are shown in the browser similar to how XML documents are shown. The document is formatted, highlighted, and arrays and objects can be collapsed. Even if the JSON document contains errors, JSONView will still show the raw text.

Comment: @ManseUK @Umesh Firefox will still prompt you to download the file if there is a `Content-Disposition: attachment` response header, even with JSONView. I have added an answer to also view these JSON files in browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888861/view-json-file-in-browser/32157007#32157007

Comment: @UmeshPatil In Chrome you should just right click by mouse and choose "Open in new tab" at the method which returns JSON data from "Network" -> "XHR" tab of Chrome browser.

Comment: Hi, Is it ok to use this way to process rsponse i angular applications?

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to install extensions, you can simply prepend the URL with `view-source:`, e.g. `view-source:http://content.dimestore.com/prod/survey_data/4535/4535.json`. This usually works in Firefox and Chrome (will still offer to download the file however if `Content-Disposition: attachment` header is present).

Comment: +1. Its cool Wladimir. Are there any other prefixes like view-source for FF ?

Comment: A bunch of them actually but they are meant for internal use - they aren't usually very useful when used manually.

Comment: @Umesh: Click "edited ... ago" link to see the change history. I changed the tags - the browser is called Firefox, Mozilla is a company/organization.

Comment: +1 for `view-source:` workaround. But this will not allow you to see the JSON file formatted in your browser with JSONView addon. And if you want to force the browser to open a file with `Content-Disposition: attachment` response header, you can remove it with moz-rewrite Firefox addon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888861/view-json-file-in-browser/32157007#32157007

Answer (score 7):

In Chrome, use JSONView to view formatted JSON.

To view "local" *.json files:
- after install You must open the Extensions option from Window menu.
- Check box next to "Allow Access to File URLs"
- note that save is automatic (i.e. no explicit save necessary)

Re-open the *.json file and it should be formatted.

Answer (score 4):

[Firefox 44](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0/releasenotes/) includes a built-in JSON viewer (no add-ons required). The feature is turned off by default, so turn on `devtools.jsonview.enabled`:
[How can you disable the new JSON Viewer/Reader in Firefox Developer Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34399282/2464)

Answer (score 2):

```
json-ie.reg. for IE
```

try this url

```
http://www.jsonviewer.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I was searching view json file in WebBrowser in my Desktop app, when I try in IE still same problem IE was also prompt to download the file. 
Luckily after too much search I find the solution for it.

You need to :
Open Notepad and paste the following:

```
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json]
    "CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
    "Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

Save document as Json.reg and then right click on file and run as administrator.

After this You can view json file in IE and you Desktop WebBrowser enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox's Bookmarks JSON files, use this excellent Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var E=document.getElementsByTagName('PRE')[0],T=E.innerHTML,i=0,r1,r2;t=new Array();while(/("uri":"([^"]*)")/g.exec(T)){r1=RegExp.$1;r2=RegExp.$2;if(/^https?:/.exec(r2)){t[i++]='['+(i)+']:<a href='+r2+'>'+r2+'<\/a>';}}with(window.open().document){for(i=0;t[i];i++)write(t[i]+'<br>');close();}})();
```

Source: "alterna" from forums.Mozillazine.org:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=5551705#p5551705

Answer (score 0):

I have the `Content-Type` of my JSON-printing CGIs set to `text/javascript`.

Works fine for both displaying in browser (e.g. Firefox) and processing in script.

Of course there's no syntax-highlighting in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `Content-Disposition: attachment` reponse header, Firefox will ask you to save the file, even if you have JSONView installed to format JSON.

To bypass this problem, I removed the header ("Content-Disposition" : null) with moz-rewrite Firefox addon that allows you to modify request and response headers https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/moz-rewrite-js/

An example of JSON file served with this header is the Twitter API (it looks like they added it recently). If you want to try this JSON file, I have a script to access Twitter API in browser: https://gist.github.com/baptx/ffb268758cd4731784e3

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend to use Notepad++ with json-view extension. You get the extension here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/
Install and restart Notepad++.
Then open json-file in Notepad and go to "extensions -> Json-Viewer - > Format JSON. Then you habe the hierarchical view of json.

You can also use one of the online-viewers (http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ , https://jsoneditoronline.org/) which look nice, but I wouldn't recommend this if your data are sensitive in terms of privacy.

Answer (score 0):

For Safari 12 and later, you can try the [JSONBeautifier](https://github.com/keithws/JSONBeautifier) bookmarklet. Also works with other browsers.

I created this because [JSON Formatter for Safari](https://github.com/rfletcher/safari-json-formatter) stopped working in Safari 12. There are a few new options for Safari 12, but I didn't find an open source one in the App Store, and I do not trust closed source browser extensions.

This can be used as a bookmarklet or the source, [json-beautifier.js](https://github.com/keithws/JSONBeautifier/blob/master/json-beautifier.js), can be copied and pasted into the browser console. The code is freely available for review and is less than 100 lines of code including comments. Runs entirely on your device and never sends your data over a network.

Works with local files too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-%3E-table/pjdecdkdljmchigbkalnblidepkeojda

Just install and open URL in browser

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Edge Browser**

### Json format easily view this but you have some changes in browser.

Browser setting
[Go to browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xmpf.png) edge://flags/

[Search Json viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xmpf.png)

[Change "Default to Enabled"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGDoJ.png)

> Restart Browser

[Done changes]

---

***Chrome Browser***

[Install Extension Json viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bopd2.png)

[Then view this pure json and change setting also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kci6K.png)

Answer (score -2):

Right click on JSON file, select open, navigate to program you want open with(notepad). Consecutive opens automatically use notepad.