# How can you disable the new JSON Viewer/Reader in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, json-view

Firefox Developer Edition 44 [now has a built in JSON Viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer). It's a nice gesture, but I highly prefer the readability of the third-party JSON viewer I was using.

Is there any way to disable, override, or otherwise customize the new built in JSON viewer?

Comment: That third-party viewer, is it http://jsonview.com/ ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. Go to about:config
2. In search, paste 'devtools.jsonview.enabled'
3. Select the pref, right-click and select 'toggle'

Comment: Firefox normal edition now ships with this feature disabled, you can enable it by toggling that setting.

Comment: Just downloaded Firefox v53.0.3 today, it seems to be enabled by default. It also seems to crash with excessively large json files.