# How to disable response preview in developers tools Firefox

Tags: firefox, development-environment, firefox-developer-tools

I want to disable response preview in developers tools (Firefox), tab network / response.
For some pages it takes a long time (and lags the browser) to render the html.

What I mean:
[image]
What I would be satisfied with:

- to have the preview pane disabled altogether
- OR to have this pane collapsed by default (with a presumption it would not be rendered in background)

What have I tried:

- searched the net & so for similar Q (found just about [json prettifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399282/how-can-you-disable-the-new-json-viewer-reader-in-firefox-developer-edition))
- browsed developers tools settings (found nothing similar)
- modified `about:config`:

  - `devtools.netmonitor.ws.payload-preview-height` set to `0` -> no cigar
  - adding new key `devtools.netmonitor.response.preview.enabled` = `false`
  - reducing max limit to payload returned with response (`devtools.netmonitor.response.ui.limit`)

so, I would appreciate any insights to solving this trouble :-)

FF version: 69.0.2 (64 bit) windows 7 64 bit