# Stop Django from rendering JSON response

Tags: json, django

I'm using Django with rest_framework and in my views I'm using the rest_framework.viewsets,
I stopped rest_framework to show it's fancy interface using:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'),
}
```

But now Django is rendering the JSON response
[image: Django JSON response]

I want it always to return **Raw Data**

How can I do that?

Comment: Django is **not** rendering that interface, it's your browser that does that for json. Check [How can you disable the new JSON Viewer/Reader in Firefox Developer Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399282/how-can-you-disable-the-new-json-viewer-reader-in-firefox-developer-edition)

Comment: You answered my 10 hours of search 

Answer (score 3):

You can try writing your `custom renderer`.

Example:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from rest_framework import renderers


class PlainTextRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'text/plain'
    format = 'txt'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return smart_text(data, encoding=self.charset)
```

The default charset with a custom renderer is `UTF-8`. If you want to change that you can read more about that here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/

Comment: Thanks my friend . It turned out to be a Firefox thing, not Django. But it also a good solution despite the fact that the returned data is OrderedDict.