# How to view a json file in any browser

Tags: json, google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge

I have a json file url.

When I access it in the browser it says to download it. I tried prepending the url with *view-source:* but it is only viewable in the FF browser and no other browser.

So I need something that I can append or prepend to the url so that the JSON file is viewable in any given browser.

Comment: It depends on the header `Content-Type` being specified: Possible duplicate question so perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Comment: I test a json file url in localhost and it only shows download when clicked in IE. It opens directly in Chrome and Edge. Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. Besides, you can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888861/view-json-file-in-browser) to use addons.

Comment: Firefox has built-in JSON viewer, but _as far as I know_ chromium based browsers doesn't, that's why.