# Using .ajaxForm and C# MVC, how can I prevent Internet Explorer from trying to save Json result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, internet-explorer

I'm returning some Json via a C# MVC Controller. Other browsers work fine, but Internet Explorer (IE9) tries to Save the returned Json data as a Text file. Any ideas how to keep this from happening?

```
//MVC Controller Code...
return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Create", "Album",
                  new { url = url, isLocalFile = isLocalFile})});

//Clientside Javascript Code
$("#uploadImageForm").ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function () {

  },
  success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
          window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
  },
  error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
  } 
});
```

I've tried adding "text/plain" and "text/json" to the second argument of the return Json method, it doesn't work.

Many thanks!

Comment: This probably has more to do with the headers being returned from the server than the way you're calling it client-side.

Comment: may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) of the `jquery.form` plugin:

> Browsers that support the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 will be able to
>   upload files seamlessly and even get progress updates as the upload
>   proceeds. For older browsers, a fallback technology is used which
>   involves iframes since it is not possible to upload files using the
>   level 1 implmenentation of the XMLHttpRequest object. This is a common
>   fallback technique, but it has inherent limitations. The iframe
>   element is used as the target of the form's submit operation which
>   means that the server response is written to the iframe. This is fine
>   if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the
>   response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented using entity references when
>   found in HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses when using
>   the iframe mode, the Form Plugin allows these responses to be embedded
>   in a textarea element and it is recommended that you do so for these
>   response types when used in conjuction with file uploads and older
>   browsers. Please note, however, that if there is no file input in the
>   form then the request uses normal XHR to submit the form (not an
>   iframe). This puts the burden on your server code to know when to use
>   a textarea and when not to.

This means that if your form contains file input fields and you are submitting this form to a controller action that returns JSON, you must wrap this JSON in a `<textarea>` tags.

So your response should not look like this:

```
{ "redirectToUrl":"some url" }
```

it should look like this:

```
<textarea>{ "redirectToUrl":"some url" }</textarea>
```

In order to achieve that you could use a custom action result that will wrap the response with those tags:

```
public class TextareaJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public TextareaJsonResult(object data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        bool shouldWrap = !context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
        if (shouldWrap)
        {
            response.Write("<textarea>");
        }

        base.ExecuteResult(context);

        if (shouldWrap)
        {
            response.ContentType = "text/html";
            response.Write("</textarea>");
        }
    }
}
```

and then have your controller action return this custom result:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // ... some processing

    var redirectToUrl = Url.Action(
        "Create", 
        "Album",
        new { url = url, isLocalFile = isLocalFile }
    );
    return new TextareaJsonResult(new { redirectToUrl = redirectToUrl });
}
```

Now obviously in your AJAX success callback you also need to account for this difference by testing the `typeof result` and in the case of a legacy browser (such as Internet Explorer) manually parse the response. You may take a look at the source code of the page I have linked to.

But this being said, I can see that in your success callback you are redirecting to a controller action contained in the JSON response returned by the server. Here comes my question: What's the point of using AJAX in the first place if you are going to redirect? Why don't you use a standard form post to the controller action and have the controller action directly perform the redirect? AJAX should be used when you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough answer. A lot explained that I didn't understand. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jesse's comment, this is probably a duplicate of the link he provided.

As such I'll provide an alternative.  I prefer to view json coming over the wire using a http proxy similar to fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ .  I mention fiddler because it works with all browsers.  The advantage is that you get a treeview of the parsed json.  It's MUCH easier to read and find what you're looking for.

Also, I believe firebug for firefox, chrome dev tools, and ie dev tool all provide the same functionality.  (I know chrome has the treeview, I think I remember firebug having it, and I would be surprised if modern IE doesn't have it considering the other 2 do.)