# Is Opening a .js file in the Browser Window of IE8+ Possible (like Firefox does)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is it possible to open a .js file in the browser window of IE8+ ? I have tried a direct URL to the file and I have also tried to write the file contents to a webpage using jquery's .load, and other methods such as XMLHttpRequest(), but in IE they all give me the Save/Open dialog.

In Firefox the direct link opens the file in the browser window and the jquery .load and the XMLHttpRequest() put the contents of the .js file right into a webpage. How can I get this behavior in IE8+ ?

Comment: Simplest answer: serve it with `Content-Type: text/plain`. Requires access to the server, obviously. :p

Comment: The answer is here, grasshopper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2492211/48082

Comment: No!  Don't do `Content-Type: text/plain`.  Bad idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convince IE to simply display application/json rather than offer to download it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do)

Comment: @Cheeso maybe? but, I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require the end users to edit their registry. They need to be able to access the file themselves, not just me.

Comment: well that's different. In that case maybe `text/plain` is the right thing.

Comment: @MindMaster - Well, it only happens in IE, so maybe you can use some VBScript there to help you out!

Comment: Or use PHP to serve the file as `text/plain`: `//www.example.com/plaintext.php?url=/blah.js`

Comment: I have tried using content-type, but I don't know what in the world I am doing with it! I found this answer from a different post: [How can I convince... ( one of the answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9527826/881519). I tried implementing it like this:  `req = new XMLHttpRequest(); if (req != undefined) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {ahahDone(url, target);};
    req.setRequestHeader("contentType","text/plain; charset = utf-8");
 req.open("GET", url, true);
 req.send("");
  }` I works in IE just as it did before. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the same domain as the calling page you can get the text with the responseText of an ajax call to the file. You can then put it in a readonly textarea or, if you turn ampersands and less-thans into entities, any html element.

Comment: should have mentioned that the file is from a different domain and they have to be logged in the access the file. I am using a text area because I am also giving the users an option to copy/paste the file contents themselves for those who have browsers that will allow it.