# Getting JSON popup to save or open dialog instead of actual content?

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, struts-config

**My Problem**: The json string returns as a file. When i call the getJSONResult action it will give me a file with the json string in it, which i can open or download.

I think it’s a configuration problem, but i can’t find it. I would be very glad if somebody could help me, thanks guys!

I have an opening form with a submit that uses an action and execute method to get the data.  Then, the only way I could get jquery to work was to put an action and execute method that just returns 'success' and then I go onto my jquery grid with a 3rd action.

struts.xml

```
<struts>
   <package name="live" namespace="/live" extends="struts-default,json-default">
      <action name="gridAction" class="core.action.AdminAction"> 
         <result name="success" type="json"></result> 
         <result name="error">/live/YYY.jsp</result> 
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: your question is not very clear to me..what problem you actually getting? are you suing struts2-json plugin?

Comment: hi Umesh , let me explain my situation first . i am using struts2 jquery for UI development and Struts2 for the flow . the issue am facing is , whenevr am trying to login my page , instead of the grid to display am getting a download popup of the JSON contents . I dont know where i done the mistake ... And am using struts2-json plugin

Comment: can you show the code and xml of relevant part? you need to use result type as `JSON`

Comment: The below is my configuration in struts.xml <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <constant name="struts.mapper.class"
  value="com.singpost.ctf.core.action.CustomActionMapper" />
 <package name="live" namespace="/live" extends="struts-default,json-default"><action name="gridAction" class="com.singpost.ctf.core.action.UserAdminGridAction">
   <result name="success" type="json"></result>
   <result name="error">/live/useradminerror.jsp</result>
  </action>

Comment: its better to update you post with code from your action and xml file to see it completely, also why you doing this `<result name="success" type="json">` as data will be sent as JSON so `<result type="json">` will also work

Comment: sorry Umesh , ik cant post the code in the action class , due to security reason in my Org . can u please suggest some other steps to avoid this bug....

Comment: can you explain it a bit more, on the first you are showing a page with loin screen and when you click login button you are sending request to server using Jquery and getting response back from the server as JSON, but its opening a pop-up?

Comment: it is difficult to help you if you can't post your code.

Comment: Ok , what part of my code you want ,,, since my action class contains more than 700 lines of code

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi , what u are asking is perfect , am getting download popup dialog , like the below two images ....http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=JSON+download+as+file&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1366&bih=575&tbm=isch&tbnid=KmaETq1pqGWqJM:&imgrefurl=http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-json-from-jax-rs-with-jaxb-resteasy/&docid=A9pzMEPWONMK7M&imgurl=http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/jaxb-json-resteasy.png

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi and like http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=JSON+download+as+file&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1366&bih=575&tbm=isch&tbnid=6dCGCGeSa7di_M:&imgrefurl=http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx%3FID%3D596&docid=ecziYCCdZg_cPM&imgurl=http://www.dotnetcurry.com/images/silverlight/26102010image_1.jpg

Comment: hi @UmeshAwasthi please suggest me what to do next , i tries searching in google , but no use , i cant find the reason y the download dialog is coming

Comment: `sorry Umesh , ik cant post the code in the action class , due to security reason in my Org` possibly you can write something on your own which you can publish. This should be more helpful

Comment: Can you use something like Fiddler to inspect the response headers? Specifically, look for the response header "Content-Disposition" and see whether it has a value of "attachment" with or without a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Internet Explorer, because I've never gotten this problem with Google Chrome (and there's even a plug-in that formats it all nicely and prettily: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)

Searching around, I've come up with two pages that offer the same solution to your problem, if indeed you are using IE:

[View JSON in Internet Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/216175/View-JSON-in-Internet-Explorer)

[How can I convince IE to simply display application/json rather than offer to download it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do)

The main gist of the solution lies here:

Need to view JSON responses in IE?

1. Open Notepad and paste the following:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00;
   ; Tell IE 7,8,9 to open JSON documents in the browser on Windows XP and later.
   ; 25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13 is the CLSID for the "Browse in place" .
   ;
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json]
   "CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
   "Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/json]
   "CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
   "Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
   ```
2. Save document as IE-Json.reg and then run it.
   Note: This has been tested on Windows XP and Windows 7 using IE 7, 8, 9.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue (struts2 issue that is), this is because you are using chrome and calling an action which returns a json result without using ajax. Some browsers would only offer you a download dialogue personally I really like that chrome shows the json string in the browser window without any fuss... it is great for debugging.

**Update**: *I didn't look at the first screen shot of IE, where you are getting the download dialogue*.

To prevent this... I assume you'll want to call the action asynchronously and since you mention using jquery (in your comments) you should probably look to [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

If this solution does not do enough for you please post the code you are using for the view because the issue lies there.