# MIME type issue with PHP? IE (and only IE) tries to download PHP files

Tags: php, ajax, json, internet-explorer, mime-types

A client is running into this problem when they try to hit a page that processes their credit card. This is the only person running into this issue, so I have to assume it's an IE specific problem or a Windows IE issue.

I'm not sure if this is a MIME type problem though. A PHP script shouldn't have its own type, correct? Since it can output binary data or text, it's up to the PHP script to return a `Content-Type` header. The only output from this `process.php` file is:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode($response));
```

Apparently this PHP script is called via Ajax. I'm not totally clear on why IE is trying to download it. Any help would be great!

PS: Unsure of IE version, finding out.

[image: File download dialog in IE]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convince IE to simply display application/json rather than offer to download it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. That user is asking how to fix his own IE browser so he can debug. My problem is that I could potentially have tons of users with this problem, and I can't just ask them all to become technologically savvy and do a registry modification.

Comment: This only happens when you directly access the file. JSON is mostly used in ajax. Besides that, you cannot manipulate a client for security reason.... if the IE doesn't know that it should display the file, you cannot do anything.

Comment: No, this is happening from an AJAX call. A user hits "pay" and it hits process.php via AJAX. This problem in IE should not be happening, but I need a way to fix it on the server side if possible. I can't tell my clients to stop using IE, unfortunately.

Comment: Remove the `Content-type` and it should work. And don't use `die()` for this. Use `echo`.