# Why IE doesn't show the Action Results on the screen

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a tutorial on ASP.Net MVC framework. 
I use Visual Studio Express and run on Intenet Explorer.

I created a new controller named CuisineController and I defined an ActionResult method named Search:

```
 public class CuisineController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Cuisine/

    public ActionResult Search(String name = "French")
    {
        var message = Server.HtmlEncode(name);
        return Json(new { Message = message, Name = "Scott" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

In the video of the tuturial when clicking on the url: "http://localhost:{portNumber}/cuisine/french" -> The json is displayed on the screen. 
In my case, I got a question from the browser:
"Do you want to open of save french.json from localhost?"

Why the browser doesn't display the json instead?

Comment: IE is asking if you want to open the contents or save it as a file. Did you click open to see what it does?

Comment: It's default behavior for IE. Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2492211