# Unable to run webapi solution in vs2017(.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Hi I started working on visual studio 2017 and trying to create small webapi application using .net core. I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api. My application name is RestPrototype. When i click on the arrow of run i can see below options. 1. RestPrototype 2. IISExpress. In visual studio  browser options were coming. When i click on the name of the application(RestProtocol) program begins to run. First one black screen appears next IE will open and close. I have attached below screen shot.

[image]

Can someone help me to run the above application? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Ur web api is working if you put debugger on ur values controller get method it should hit that

Comment: you have to change a registry key for IE to render JSON and not prompt to save a file - see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2483771/495455

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clicking on your project name RestProtocol under Run option your project gets started and it gets self hosted.
So you able to see whether the port number assigned to your project is active or not using Resource Monitor in your system.
If it is active use Postman or other rest client to give Web API request that you had created in your project. You can see your rest API will works.
I tried this it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try using postman, I am able to debug and get result as expected. In vs2015 I was able to display result in browser itself. Now one json file is downloading in downloads that contains required results.