# Protect my code from Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am building a textbook .NET WebAPI web service, which is supposed in the most simplistic case receive a GET request and return a JSON array of objects.

But the project also loads NewtonsoftJSON nuget package, and apparently that package re-defines the `ApiController` class, so that its `Json()` method has a different declaration. The end result is that I get the following compile time error:

[image]

**How can I protect the declaration of my controller from being re-defined by Newtonsoft?**

```
public class ImmediateInformationController : ApiController
{
    public JsonResult Get([FromUri] ImmediateInformation ii)
    {
        // some code here
        return this.Json(iil, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

A bit of a background: initially I was returning just `iil`, but when testing in the browser, it prompted to download `ImmediateInformation.json` file, which contained the JSON I needed. The above was an attempt to have the JSON returned as plain text, and that lead me to the discovery that Newtonsoft re-defined `ApiController` when parameter types did not match MSDN documentation.

[image]

**Just to re-cap: the question is only using JSON download issue to illustrate what I was doing. How can I ensure that when I am declaring the controller class to be a descendant of `ApiController`, it is Microsoft's API controller, and not Newtonsoft's?**

Comment: You seem to be mixing up MVC and WebAPI namespaces/code... [JsonRequestBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is ASP.Net MVC enum and should not be used in WebAPI code (same for attributes that have same names in two namespaces). Posting more complete [MCVE] with namespaces would make it clear...

Comment: Yeah, I realized that since. My problem is that I only know of WebAPI for about 2 hours, so making some silly mistakes, and the references like Newtonsoft re-defining MVC classes confused be beyond belief.

Answer (score 5):

Web API 2 includes JSON.NET by default, and uses that in its [Json() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Your tutorial probably doesn't target Web API 2, but an earlier version, or [MVC instead of Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430920(v=vs.118).aspx).

Either omit the JsonRequestBehavior:

```
return this.Json(iil);
```

Or simply return the proper return type and let Web API handle the serialization:

```
public ImmediateInformation Get([FromUri] ImmediateInformation ii)
{
    return ii;
}
```

Which you could also do using an IHttpActionResult:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] ImmediateInformation ii)
{
    return this.Ok(ii);
}
```

According to your edit and comment, you're actually looking for [How can I convince IE to simply display application/json rather than offer to download it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do).

Comment: I've initially returned POCO, but was confused when the browser popped up a download prompt for the file called `<model name>.json` and started looking for a way to simply return the result in the body of the response. This probably lead me on a wild goose chase above. Sounds like something is wrong with the default content disposition.

Comment: I guess you use Internet Explorer, which doesn't like rendering JSON.

Comment: If I returned the same JSON from .ashx, it would be displayed. I asked another question for this issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/48777442/2721750

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fully qualify the parameter.

```
return this.Json(iil, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or you can use an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/how-to-use-the-global-namespace-alias).

```
using NJson = Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: I am not `using` Newtonsoft, it is used by one of the referenced nuget packages (MigraDocs).

Comment: Ah, so alias is out then.

Comment: Fully qualifying is also out, as it's the `ApiController` class which is re-defined by Newtonsoft (or its method `Json`), but the `JsonRequestBehaviour` is fine.

Comment: I see, and your updates to the question make that clear now. I would go with CodeCaster's suggestions then.