# Display JSON in IE as HTML Without Download

Tags: json, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I want JSON files and downloads to be displayed directly in the IE browser -- Browse in Place.
There are many posts that describe the technique of setting the CLSID value for application/json in the browser.

For example:
[How can I convince IE to simply display application/json rather than offer to download it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do)

I have tested on IE 11 (11.0.9600.17416) and Windows 10.

I changed the setting and even then rebooted, but I am always prompted to download the JSON.

[image]

EDIT:
After running the script to alter regedit, I see the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I try to refer the answer in that [referenced thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-do).

I made this test on Windows 10, IE 11 (11.1.18362.0) version.

I simply try to refer the steps below.

(1) Try to open Notepad and paste the code below in it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;
; Tell IE to open JSON documents in the browser.  
; 25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13 is the CLSID for the "Browse in place" .
;  

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/json]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

(2) Save the File with name as **json-ie.reg**

(3) Double click the file to run the script and allow it to create a key.

(4) Try to double click the json file and it opens in IE 11 without any issue.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Retried again.  It doesn't work.  The JSON file opens into Notepad instead of IE.

Comment: Make sure you created the registry entry properly and please inform us how you exactly open the json file? did you try to paste the URL in address bar? Does it still shows the download prompt?

Comment: - Created the json-ie.reg file as described above.  Double clicked.
- I added a screenshot of the registry after doing that in the original post.
- I had been attempting to download a sample JSON file from this page:
    https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/208047697-JSON-sample-files
    It prompts to open or save as shown in the original post.
- I also now tried your method of just double clicking to open a JSON file from disk.  It launches into NotePad.
It seems like there must be some other setting that I'm missing.
- Thanks for your comments.

Comment: After setting the registry, try to follow these steps. Right click on any json file on your machine. Select 'open with' option and click on 'choose another app'. then select Internet Explorer and checked the 'Always use this app to open .json files' checkbox. https://i.postimg.cc/259JKprW/314.png Then try to open the json file. it will be open in IE.